# Multiple type case in switch

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, swift4

I know that is possible to:

```swift
enum MyEnum {
    case label
    case view
    case textField
}

let type = TypeEnum.label

switch type {
    case .label, .textField: break //I want to this but with type.
    case .view: break
}
```

And I want to know how to make a condition testing types with switch.

Something like:

```swift
switch view {
    case is UILabel, is UITextField: break
    case is UIView: break
}
```

Edited:

I know what I did wrong.

```swift
switch view {
    case is UILabel, 
         is UITextField,
         is UILabel: break //It was telling me that this case would 
                           //never be executed. In my tests I forgot
                           //to remove the duplicate.
    case is UIView: break
}
```

Anyway thanks Rob, I didn't knew about the `fallthrough`

Comment: I was looking for an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Something happened with the compiler, it is working now.

Comment: @ThiagoNicolau This code seems fishy. If you need to test for something being a UILabel, UITextField, or UIView, you most probably should define a protocol, extend those 3 types with it, and implement a method on the protocol with whatever functionality you were going to put in the switch body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fallthrough`:

```
switch view {
    case is UILabel:     fallthrough
    case is UITextField: print("is label or text field")
    default:             print("is something else")
}
```